# Using demo cards from cardslib

Tags: android, android-cardview, cardslib

I've been trying to use the [cardslib lirary](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) in a project I'm working on. I've successfully compiled and ran apps using the [native cards](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/GUIDE.md#feature).

I'm interested in using [google birthday cards](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/EXAMPLE.md#birthday-card-source) in my project. But being a novice android developer as I am, I have no idea how I would proceed. How do I include those demo cards in my project so I can customize and use them to my liking.

Also, I'm using Android Studio.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define this card.

Here you can find all the code in demo app:

[Fragment:](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/demo/stock/src/main/java/it/gmariotti/cardslib/demo/fragment/nativeview/NativeBirthDayCardFragment.java)

[Card code](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/demo/stock/src/main/java/it/gmariotti/cardslib/demo/cards/GoogleNowBirthCard.java)

Comment: I've tried that. I cannot import the demo package.  
`import it.gmariotti.cardslib.demo.cards.GoogleNowBirthCard;`
This cannot resolve the symbol `demo`.  
Is there some other dependency I should be adding? I've only added those that you have mentioned in your [getting started guide](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/GUIDE.md#including-in-your-project).  
  
Btw, it's an awesome library you have built. Thank you.

Comment: Check the demo code. It is simply a package. You can use your own package of course.

Comment: I am sorry to say this, but I haven't really done much java either. I tried copying the `demo/stock/src/main` folder from the library source code into my project's `src` folder. That didn't work. Could you kindly guide me on how I would go about doing that correctly?

Comment: The library package doesn't show any error. My main package doesn't either - that is until I try to import the demo packages. (`import it.gmariotti.cardslib.demo.R;` etc). In that case I get package doesn't exist error. (`Error:(17, 34) error: package it.gmariotti.cardslib.demo does not exist`). Also, I have tried cleaning the project but to no avail.